# Query sys.database_principals on the basis of sid

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have situation here, I need to check if the user is present in sys.database_principals table but on the basis of its SID.

I tried to execute simple query.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_principal
 where [sid] = '0x............'
```

but it returned nothing.
as sid is varbinary(85). Do I need to have some conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Don't enclose binary literals in quotes. Otherwise the value is treated as a string literal instead of binary literal.

The sid varbinary(85) data type has a lower [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than the varchar literal so the sid value is converted from binary to varchar for the comparison and the resultant characters will not compare equal.

Corrected query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_principal
WHERE [sid] = 0x............;
```